# Conditional variable and rwlock deadlock

Tags: linux, multithreading, locking, posix

I have a simple threaded program which use a conditional variable and a rwlock. I've been staring at it for hours trying different approaches. The problem is that a thread or more stops at the rwlock after a while although it is not locked for writing. Maybe I miss something about how those locks work or how they are implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//global variables
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock;
int counter;
int listLength = 1;

void* worker(void* arg){
   do {
      usleep(200);
      printf("Before rwlock\n");
      pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
      printf("Before mutex\n");
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      printf("Afer mutex\n");
      counter++;
      //signal the main
      if (counter == 5 ||
               (listLength < 5 && counter == listLength)){
          printf("Signal main\n");
          pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
          counter = 0;
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
   } while(listLength != 0);

   return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc != 2){
        perror("Invalid number of args");
        exit(1);
    }
    //get arguments
    int workers = atoi(argv[1]);

    //initialize sync vars
    pthread_rwlockattr_t attr;
    pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np(&attr,
            PTHREAD_RWLOCK_PREFER_WRITER_NONRECURSIVE_NP);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock, &attr);
    counter = 0;

    //create threads
    pthread_t threadArray[workers];
    int threadOrder[workers];
    for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++){
        threadOrder[i] = i;
        if (pthread_create(&threadArray[i], NULL,
                    worker, &threadOrder[i]) != 0){
            perror("Cannot create thread");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    while(listLength != 0) {
        //wait for signal and lock the list
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex) != 0);
        pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
        printf("In write lock\n");

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
        printf("release wrlock\n");
    }

    //join the threads
    for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++){
        if (pthread_join(threadArray[i], NULL) !=0){
            perror("Cannot join thread");
           exit(1);
        }
    }

    //release resources
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    pthread_rwlock_destroy(&rwlock);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks  like this code has several inconsistencies in it.

1. You're using `mutex` together with `rwlock` which means that all the threads of this kind are always locked. If you *remove* the `rwlock` code - it won't change the behaviour.
2. I cannot see the `pthread_rwlock_init()` call, and suppose you've called it in another place. Anyway pay attention you *do* call it and you *don't call it twice* or more times with the same rowlock object.

   The same applies to `pthread_rwlockattr_destroy()`
3. I cannot see the reason why pthread_rwlock_rdlock() would block without write lock. Be sure you don't do it. Or else you could do a mutual lock of your `mutex`

Comment: Worker threads have some extra work to do between rwlock and mutex, but I took it out to be easier to spot the problem. If I take out the rwlock code it doesn't get stuck however I need it for the extra work. `pthread_rwlock_init()` is in the first part of the main function. I can't see either a reason why it shouldn't work. It works with only one worker thread, it gets stuck with more than one.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. The deadlock was caused by trying to writelock when the mutex was locked so all worker threads would readlock and wait at the mutex while the main thread would wait at the writelock.